# Flutter passing parameters in the builder

Tags: flutter, builder, flutter-build

I've been working with flutter_builder for a few days. I think the system is very powerful and I really like it, but I still need to understand some information.
In order to run the builder you need to run the following command: flutter pub run build_runner build.
My question is to know if it is possible to pass parameters in order to make it as customizable as possible, such as when entering commands on the java -jar command etc.
Thanks everyone for the reply